# Does assigning a list equivalent to deepcopy() or copy()?

Tags: python, list, copy, assignment-operator

Does the assignment operator work as a `deepcopy()` or `copy()`?

For example, if I assign a list `a` to list `b`, does it create a shallow copy or a deep copy of list `a`?

Answer (score 0):

***It is neither `copy()` nor `deepcopy()`.***

In Python, all variables are of reference type. So once you assign one list to another then they both represent the same address. So if you `update/add/delete` element of the list then the same changes will happen in list b also.

So if the list is having only immutable elements then you can use `copy()` to create a copy but if the list is having mutable elements as well so you need to use `deepcopy()`

```
import copy
b=a.copy()    #If list a elements are immutable
c=a.deepcopy()   #If list a elements are mutable
```